# difference between cnn and vgg model in neural network

Tags: neural-network, vgg-net

What is VGG model in neural network?

I think VGG model has specific specifications:
   -Convolutions layers (used only 3*3 size )
   -Max pooling layers (used only 2*2 size)
   -Fully connected layers at end
   -Total 16 layers

What is the difference betwwen CNN and VGG model in neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's a bit semantic, CNN is a concept of a neural network, Its main attributes may be that it consists of convolution layers, pooling layers , activation layers etc.

VGG is a specific convolutional network designed for classification and localization.Like many other popular networks like Google-Net, Alex Net etc.